# Can the onborad LAN cause computer shutdown

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard

I have P4 processor with nvidia card. Now if i don't connect to internet then my computer stays on for as much i can like 4-5 days. But if i plug in the ethernet wire. Do some surfing and leave computer as it is. Then computer fails. I mean

1. The display on screen gets off
2. Looks like something stopping the power supply to Harddisk.

But motherboard stays on , FAN is still running , i can eject CD drive as well.
But no display on monitor.

I have to turn off and then turn on again.

I tried formatting windows XP but again same problem

Comment: What you are describing sounds more like the system went into S1 standby mode. What happens if you press a key or click the mouse when it gets shut down like that?

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is that the default driver for your network adapter is buggy. Did you try updating it? It's also possible that it's overheating. Check your temps. Running memtest86 wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: u mean the temperature of lan card or cpu

Comment: The CPU temperature. Perhaps you're unintentionally running a processor-intensive load whenever you're connected to the Internet, compared to when you're not.